# Passar lista para o model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Tenho uma consulta que me retorna uma lista dessa maneira:

```
var list = db.Comentario.Where(d => d.GrupoTrabalhoId == Id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DataComentario).ToList();
```

Após essa consulta, ela me retornará entre outras coisas o Id do usuário, eu gostaria de obter o nome. então pensei em fazer um foreach e consultar o nome pelo id do usuário, ficaria assim:

```
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
      model.Id = item.Id;
      model.GrupoTrabalhoId = item.GrupoTrabalhoId;
      model.Comentario = item.Comentario;
      model.UsuarioId = item.UsuarioId;
      //ABAIXO EU FARIA A NOVA CONSULTA
      model.NomeUsuario = dbUsuario.Usuarios.Where(d => d.UsuarioID == item.UsuarioId).Select(s => s.Nome).FirstOrDefault();;
      model.DataComentario = item.DataComentario;
    }
```

só que do jeito que está isso irá sobrepondo a cada loop do foreach.

o código completo ficaria assim:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ListaComentario(int Id)
{

   using (var db = new ContextoComentario())
   {
      var list = db.Comentario.Where(d => d.GrupoTrabalhoId == Id).OrderByDescending(s => s.DataComentario).ToList();

     var model = new ComentarioModel();
     var dbUsuario = new ContextoUsuario();


     foreach (var item in list)
     {
        model.Id = item.Id;
        model.GrupoId = item.GrupoId;
        model.Comentario = item.Comentario;
        model.UsuarioId = item.UsuarioId;
        model.NomeUsuario = dbUsuario.Usuarios.Where(d => d.UsuarioID == item.UsuarioId).Select(s => s.Nome).FirstOrDefault();
        model.DataComentario = item.DataComentario;
      }

       return View(model);
   }
}
```

------**REPOSTA ATUALIZADA**------

eu fiz como o colega falou ai abaixo, criar uma lista model e a cada loop inserir um novo. veja abaixo. mas não teria uma outra forma mais elegante de fazer isso ?

```
var model =  new List<ComentarioModel>();
var dbUsuario = new ContextoUsuario();

foreach (var item in list)
{
   var comentario = new ComentarioModel();
   comentario.Id = item.Id;
   comentario.GrupoTrabalhoId = item.GrupoTrabalhoId;
   comentario.Comentario = item.Comentario;
   comentario.UsuarioId = item.UsuarioId;
   comentario.NomeUsuario = dbUsuario.Usuarios.Where(d => d.UsuarioID == item.UsuarioId).Select(s => s.Nome).FirstOrDefault();
   comentario.DataComentario = item.DataComentario;
    model.Add(comentario);
}
```

Comment: E qual é sua dúvida? Porque no `Comentario` você não dá um `Include` no `Usuarios`?

Comment: então, a dúvida é " do jeito que está isso irá sobrepondo a cada loop do foreach "

Comment: Por que você captura uma exceção só pra lançá-la de novo?

Comment: Cria uma lista de model e a cada loop você irá inserir um novo model na lista de models.

Comment: @Maniero é porque tava dando erro :) . vou tirar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas mais elegantes de ser fazer isto.

Mas pode ser simplificado da seguinte forma:

```
var model = list.Select(item => new ComentarioModel
{
   Id = item.Id,
   GrupoTrabalhoId = item.GrupoTrabalhoId,
   Comentario = item.Comentario,
   UsuarioId = item.UsuarioId,
   NomeUsuario = dbUsuario.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UsuarioID == item.UsuarioId),
   DataComentario = item.DataComentario
});
```

Comment: Legal, muito bom .